# Cant able to close the form

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have two forms....Form A and Form B....i open the Form A first, minimize it and then opened the Form B.

Now i closed the Form A and after that when i am clicking the close form button or EXIT button to close the Form B an the error "FRM-40735 POST FORM trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06508" is coming.

I searched the error code for form and oracle. But not got anything.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2344836

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2550526

What is the way to fix this.Please help

Comment: ORA-06508 is a compilation error - look at what your form B's POST-FORM trigger calls, and check that the code (might be a database package or procedure) is all valid.

Comment: @PuneetKushwah can you post the code within the trigger POST-FORM?